# Implementing Onclick in Android Studio 3.5 Navigation Drawer template

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-studio-3.5

I have been using the old Android Studio and I had no problems with the navigation drawer template. I Updated my android studio to 3.5 and now I cannot seem to find am method that runs a function onClick on a certain menu item. I am trying to run a method where a navigation drawer item is clicked and a Toast Message is displayed. I have tried using navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener method but it only works on default fragments and when they are opened. I want the Toast message to be displayed without opening any fragment. This is how I have done it so far :

```
DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    //removing tint
    navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);

    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.change_language, R.id.nav_slideshow,
            R.id.nav_tools, R.id.nav_share, R.id.nav_send)
            .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);


    navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(new NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDestinationChanged(@NonNull NavController controller, @NonNull
                NavDestination destination, @Nullable Bundle arguments) {
            if (destination.getId() == R.id.nav_home) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Home has been clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            if (destination.getId() == R.id.nav_gallery) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Gallery Has been clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
            || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
}
```

Comment: use getApplicationContext() other than calling mainActivity.this @DwayneT